# Can't inject BackgroundService into PageModel

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to use the BackgroundService is an asp.net core 2.2 project using the Razor page project template, not MVC. This little sample app took me about 1 minute to write so it couldn't be much simpler. Looking at the debugger I know the background service is starting and chugging along just fine. But when I attempt to navigate to a page (path 'Banana') that requires this service as a dependency, I get `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApplication23.DumbService' while attempting to activate 'WebApplication23.Pages.BananaModel'.` Why can't I access this service from my page model? The code is at https://github.com/jmagaram/SimpleBackgroundService

I have the following service:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication23
{
    public class DumbService : BackgroundService
    {
        public DumbService()
        {

        }

        public void QueueWork()
        {

        }

        protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where I register it:

```
services.AddHostedService<DumbService>();
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Here is a page model that uses it:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication23.Pages
{
    public class BananaModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly DumbService _service;

        public BananaModel(DumbService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A background service is something that runs by itself in the background, not something that's meant to be injected into controllers or PageModels. It's not meant to be a singleton service. If you want to stop/start/administer it from your PageModel, you'll have to register it the same as any other service

Comment: As Chris Pratt explains, whatever the real problem is, it can be solved *without* injecting a background service into the page model. If that service does some heavy lifting on posted messsages for example, you only need an interface that allows posting to it (eg an IWriter), not access to the service itself.

Comment: Yes my page model only needs access to a single method on the background service, something like “QueueWork(...)”. I’ll see if I can get that injected into my page model rather than the whole background service. But then that new tightly focused service will need the background service injected into it as a dependency. I’ll see if I can get that to work.

Comment: You can create an interface with that method that's implemented by the service. In `ConfigureServices` you can call the [AddSingleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection___0_)  overload that acceps a ready-made instance and pass the background service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registering a background service doesn't actually add it to the service collection, mostly because there's no need to. The whole point of a background service is that your app doesn't really need to know about it. It's not clear why you think you need this service injected, but almost certainly you'd be better served by factoring out whatever logic you need in your Razor Page into a separate class that both the service and your Razor page can utilize.

**UPDATE**

See the [documentation on `IHostedService` where an example of a queue background service is given](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2#queued-background-tasks). You'll notice that the actual hosted service is injected with the task queue. Your app then would also inject just the task queue itself to schedule tasks.

Comment: The background service exposes a method like “QueueWork(...)” And that method is what I need to call from my page model. I’ll try refactoring just that into a new service but THAT service will need to have the background service injected into its constructor as a dependency. So either the background service gets injected into the PageModel or it gets injected into another service that gets injected into the page model.

Comment: Yes I got that to work. It seems a little inside out to me. I created a service called IWorkQueue, made it a singleton, and injected that into my background service AND into the PageModel.

Comment: Not really. `IHostedService` implementations are not part of the application domain. It doesn't make sense to inject a service that is itself independent of the application it would be injected into. This would create all sorts of issues with how services would have to start/stop and create a hard dependency in the application layer that's loose on purpose. An externalized queue allows both sides to operate independently of each other. Your app just schedules tasks without worry of how or when they're processed. The service just runs tasks without worry of where they came from.